# Run a Python Script Stored in an AWS S3 Bucket on EC2 and Save Resulting File Back into S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, pickle

I have a Python script stored in an S3 bucket. I'd like to have it run in AWS (an EC2 instance presumably) and save its output (a pickle file) back into the same S3 bucket.

In the Python script itself, you specify a filename and just call to_pickle:

```
def metadata_df(search_api,hashtags,since,until,filename,lat_long_only=True):

    if os.path.exists(filename):
        df = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    else:
        df = ...

    df.to_pickle(filename)
    return df

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pickle_name = yesterday+'_'+'tweets.pkl'
    metadata_df(api.search, hashtags, since=yesterday,until=today, filename=pickle_name,lat_long_only=True)
...
```

Wondering how I go about doing this (only need to run this a single time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your EC2 instance need to have Read/Write access to S3. For instance, using the role, based on AmazonS3FullAccess policy.

Then insight the instance you can use [aws s3 copy cli command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) to copy files between the instance and S3 bucket.

Then within your instance:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/mypythonscript.py .
python mypythonscript.py
aws s3 cp ./resultfile.ext s3://mybucket
```

Comment: instead of using aws s3 cp , can we do both these operations in python script itself? May be we can use BOTO3, anyone ?